# How to use included library functions in a C++ header file to define private variables

Tags: c++, function, header, include

I am new to C++ but not programming and have recently started to write a library for a AVR micro-controller. My header file (Codex.h) for my library looks like this..

```
#ifndef Codex_h
#define Codex_h
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>

class Codex
{
public:
    void hostIP(int a ,int b ,int c,int d);
    void start(String ID);
    void digitalReadOSC();
    void analogReadOSC();
    void digitalRead();
    void analogRead();
    void receive();
private:
    EthernetUDP _Udp;
    int _pin,_a,_b;
    int _sensorData[52];
    String _nID,_sID,_pID,_snID,_lID,_payloadlen,_payload,_packet;
    char _packetBuffer[25];
    IPAddress _coreIP(000,000,0,00);
};
#endif
```

Now Il say again I am new to C++ so I think i'm making a simple mistake but my compiler is having a problem with the IPAddress type and processing the EthernetUDP instance creation. IPAddress is a function which comes from the Ethernet.h library.Here is what my compiler spits out when I try to include my library in a project.

```
In file included from sketch_aug17b.ino:1:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Codex/Codex.h:19: error: 'EthernetUDP' 
does not name a type
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Codex/Codex.h:24: error: 'IPAddress' 
does not name a type
```

Thanks in advance for any help given even if it is just to tell me to go and read a C++ book :).

Comment: Have you checked the spellings?  `EthernetUdp` perhaps, based on file name?  Maybe IpAddress on a hunch...

Comment: Have you check if they are inside namespace?

Comment: @Reuben Why are you keeping your header file in a standard directory ? Its a bit unusual to keep user header files in the Program Files path. It confuses whether errors are coming from the standard headers or your own.

Comment: The error is defiantly coming from my header file, I don't see how my header file being in (/Program Files) would add to any ambiguity to where the error is originating. The included header files are standard for the arduino IDE.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good stab at it, but the [header](http://code.google.com/p/arduino/issues/attachmentText?id=669&aid=6690001000&name=EthernetUdp.h&token=ed17839fafdb14485f9d69c2314e3a11) appears to indeed be [`EthernetUDP`](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/ethernet). (it was my first guess as well, btw).

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned by @WhozCraig there is no problem with the classes names, nor the classes are inside a scope. So my best guess is that you are trying to instantiate a member variable (**_coreIP**) outside a method. You should fist declare the member variable on the class declaration, and then instantiate it on the constructor of the class.

So change this.

```
class Codex
{
...
private:
    ...
    IPAddress _coreIP(000,000,0,00);
};
```

for this

```
class Codex
{
public:
    ...
    Codex();
private:
    ...
    IPAddress _coreIP;
};

Codex::Codex() :
  _coreIP(000,000,0,00)
{
    ...
}
```

You can instantiate member variables directly on the constructor of the class, using the : operator as is showed here.

By the way, this is my first answer, so I hope I had done it well :)

Greetings

Comment: Hmm, true, but weird how the EthernetUDP would not work, then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I solved it but am a still bit confused (new to C++).I did actually also have a problem with the (_coreIP) variable, as I was trying to initialize it in the header file, again thanks for taking the time to post a answer.

Answer (score 0):

My code is now working, I'm not sure if it was a genuine mistake or something else is going on, but after including the external header files needed in my library in my working program that uses my class I no longer get any problems, if someone could explain to me why this is so that would be great. my new header code and program code.

```
//(Codex.h)
#ifndef Codex_h
#define Codex_h
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>

class Codex
{
public:
    void hostIP(int a ,int b ,int c,int d);
    void start(String ID);
    void digitalReadOSC();
    void analogReadOSC();
    void digitalRead();
    void analogRead();
    void receive();
private:
    int _pin,_a,_b;
    int _sensorData[52];
    String _nID,_sID,_ndID,_pID,_snID,_lID,_payloadlen,_payload,_packet;
    char _packetBuffer[25];
    EthernetUDP _Udp;
    IPAddress _coreIP;
};
#endif
```

This is my program , although its seems unusual that I would have to declare my needed libraries a second time in my program if they are already declared in my .h and .cpp file.

```
#include <Codex.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>

Codex codex;
void setup()
{
codex.start("01");  
}
void loop()
{ 
}
```